# Slow queries with binding parameters on Laravel using SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, binding, laravel-8

In my application, I need to `count` rows in my view. So I'm using the Laravel Query Builder. It works as expected, but it takes a lot of time to count rows. After some debugging, I figure out what causes this increase in time. It's because of the binding.

**Database parameters**

```
'bi' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('BI_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('BI_DB_PORT', '1433'),
    'database' => env('BI_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('BI_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('BI_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'trust_server_certificate' => 'true',
    // 'encrypt' => 'yes',
],
```

**Here's my debug**

```php
DB::connection('bi')->enableQueryLog();

DB::connection('bi')->select('SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM [DMAT].[VW_ORDER] WHERE [COMPANY] = \'My Company\'');
$debug['select no binding'] = DB::connection('bi')->getQueryLog();
DB::connection('bi')->flushQueryLog();

DB::connection('bi')->select('SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM [DMAT].[VW_ORDER] WHERE [COMPANY] = :company', ['company' => 'My Company']);
$debug['select named binding'] = DB::connection('bi')->getQueryLog();
DB::connection('bi')->flushQueryLog();

DB::connection('bi')->table('DMAT.VW_ORDER')
    ->where('COMPANY', 'My Company')
    ->count();
$debug['queryBuilder'] = DB::connection('bi')->getQueryLog();
DB::connection('bi')->flushQueryLog();

dd($debug);
```

**Result of debugging**

```php
array:3 [▼
  "select no binding" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "query" => "SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM [DMAT].[VW_ORDER] WHERE [COMPANY] = 'My Company'"
      "bindings" => []
      "time" => 1424.41
    ]
  ]
  "select named binding" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "query" => "SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM [DMAT].[VW_ORDER] WHERE [COMPANY] = :company"
      "bindings" => array:1 [▼
        "company" => "My Company"
      ]
      "time" => 90870.69
    ]
  ]
  "queryBuilder" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "query" => "select count(*) as aggregate from [DMAT].[VW_ORDER] where [COMPANY] = ?"
      "bindings" => array:1 [▼
        0 => "My Company"
      ]
      "time" => 88536.85
    ]
  ]
]
```

As you can see, using **SELECT** without binding is much faster than **SELECT** with binding. I don't understand why. Has someone had this issue before?

I tested it using pure **PHP** with **PDO**. The results still the same.

`time php sqlsrv.php`

```php
<?php
$conn = new \PDO(
    "sqlsrv:Server=$host,1433;Database=$dataBase;TrustServerCertificate=1",
    $userName,
    $password
);

$sql = 'SELECT count(*) as aggregate FROM [DMAT].[VW_ORDER] WHERE COMPANY = :company';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$company = 'My Company';
$stmt->bindParam(':company', $company);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($data);
```

Result:

```sh
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aggregate] => 423
        )

)

real    0m57.534s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.044s
```

I'm using

- Laravel Framework 8.68.1
- PHP 7.4.20 (cli)

Comment: Please share the fast and slow query plans via https://pastetheplan.com. Please also [edi]t your question and add relevant table and index definitions. This question is not answerable without this information

Comment: I'm guessing you need an index on `(COMPANY)` although single column indexes are not useful for other types of queries and you may want to add more columns also

Comment: I'm justin consuming a view in SQL Server, I don't have access to view source.
But the point is. If I use binding, the SQL response takes a very long time. Without binding it take much less time.

Comment: And my point is that without further detail we cannot help you. It is most likely an issue with the query plan, not binding per se. So we need the query plans to help you

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the same problem with some differences. The differences are:

1. I have mysql.
2. When using a pure PDO with parameter bindings the response time is fast enough.

So I found that there are different options for pure PDO and Laravel PDO. The option that makes difference for me was `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`. This option was enabled for the pure PDO and was disabled for the Laravel PDO. I enabled it for the Laravel PDO and I get a fast response with parameter bindings.

To enable the option, open the Config/database.php and add:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            // Some other options
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => 1,
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Comment: Hey dude, I have been wondering on these for weeks, on raw SQL the queries are fast, but on DB::table with a lot of arguments are very slow, tried this one and it works like magic. Thanks